# Can a precognitive dodge modern firearms?

Tags: super-powers, firearms, precognition

If you have a physically fit individual who can see up to 5 seconds in the future, is it possible for them to not get hit by bullets by moving away?

(Precognition being defined here as the ability to sense hundreds of futures based on the likelihood that they will occur by doing given actions, plus the processing power to process this information. Precognition is primarily sight and pain.)

Practically speaking, in most ranges, by the time the bullet is in motion it's too late for the individual to change whether or not they get hit, but what about moving before the trigger is pulled, or feinting, or something like that?

If so, what ranges would this be feasible at, and what kinds of guns would be possible to dodge? Pistols? Sniper rifles?

I imagine sustained fire would be almost impossible to dodge without cover.

Comment: do they see 5seonds into the future continuously or as discrete events?

Comment: I know this sounds crazy but I think they can use shields to further protect themselves.
First is a large solid kevlar, or something similar, shield that they can carry.
If that is hard then a very large back-bag lined again with kevlar or something like AR500 steel.
If you at least know the direction of shot then putting this shield tthat the direction would provide more protection.
They will still have to contend with the energy of the bullet hitting the shield and possibly breaking their bones. But that is better than dying.
They can also throw the shield/bag or at throw it and run.

Comment: Does the precognative ability include meta-precognition? That is, can they see the futures of choices they've made as a result of precognative visions?

Comment: @Seallussus Kevlar cannot stop rifle rounds at all, and steel is heavy. Ceramic would be better, but it would still be very heavy. And a bullet hitting a shield you are holding will probably not break any bones. The bullet cannot exert more force on you than it did on the person who fired it (equal and opposite forces). They deal damage by concentrating force in a small area, not with raw energy. After all, if a bullet could break your bone through a shield, which would presumably spread the force out greatly, then it would also probably break the arm of the shooter.

Comment: @RichardSmith,
I am just providing more ideas to how he maybe protect himself.
We don't know what round he is facing so being against that without context is like saying to a police officer that wears his vest: That's stupid, a rifle rounds will kill you. I think we all know that it is better than nothing is the prefer answer to this.
It all depends on context to whither or not the shield will hurt him.
I was thinking of rifle rounds or high-powered rifles.
Probably does not equal always and again better than nothing when it comes to life or death.

Comment: Have you seen the end of the movie Next (2007)?

Comment: While they might not be able to dodge gun*fire* they will be able to dodge gun*fights* quite effectively.

Comment: This scenario is the basic assumption of the Alex Verus series by Beendict Jacka. Though he adds some depth by making the limitations somewhat varied: counterspells, being distracted, different modes of concentration, how well the precog is trained, etc. He also explains a ton of alternate usages for precog: Never slip in the dark, know where enemies are in fog (by checking what futures he'll bump into opponents), password hacking (failed attempts "look" so similar that he can easily identify the successful future).

Comment: Note that any arbitrary time limit can be circumvented. E.g. I want to know whether a coin tossed in T + 10 seconds will be heads or tails. At T + 5 I look ahead to T + 10, and write down the outcome on a piece of paper. At T + 0 I look ahead to T + 5 and see what is written on the paper.

Comment: You'd be fine until you encountered a shooter who is also a precog.  That might be a good idea for your end-boss..

Comment: Second encounter, I bring a blunderbuss.

Comment: @John Anything within a 5-second interval.

Comment: @Dragongeek yes, but the more choices involved, the less they're aware of that future.

Comment: @JBentley technically not if you don't have enough time to write the thing, also in this case there are too many possibilities, and it takes into account everything that you could do, not everything you are likely to do, so you cannot predict your own choices like writing down the future, since you could potentially write down anything.

Comment: For single shots it may be better to catch bullets than to evade them - just carry a steel cup-shaped catcher ~10 mm thick.

Comment: @Piomicron that doesn't answer my question. If they use their ability can they use it again immediately or do they have to wait until the 5 seconds elapse. basically do they always see 5 sec into the future all the time.

Comment: Non-precognitive people can also dodge bullets by moving away...

Comment: If you could see into the future at all, why would it not be possible to avoid bullets by moving away?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Because the future isn't fixed, and if you move then the shooter can adjust their aim.

Comment: @Piomicron How does that not negate your own Question?

Further, can you clarify how "in most ranges, by the time the bullet is in motion it's too late for the individual to change whether or not they get hit, but what about moving before the trigger is pulled, or feinting, or something like thatæ" or "… what ranges would this be feasible…" or "… what kinds of guns…" relate to precognition?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin What I mean to say is, that the shooter's actions are by no means fixed, so if they see you moving they could potentially adjust their aim. The first quote refers to the fact that if a bullet is headed towards the centre of your chest or head, unless you are very far away it's physically impossible to move fast enough for it to miss by the time the bullet leaves the barrel. Any manoeuvres must be milliseconds from completion by the time it's shot, unless it's long-range.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin What I want to know, though, is if a precognitive could, for example, begin movement before the gun is fired such that they could not be in the path of the bullet, successfully avoid ever being put in the crosshair, or be expected to trick the shooter into firing too far by feinting.

Comment: @Piomicron I thought everyone thought that's what you wanted to know and the Answer is still yes, of course. That's what "precog" is for. If you want to make the shooter a precog, too, either that makes a different Question or they chase each other through an infinite series of time loops, or both.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Can you prove it? Or at least, demonstrate that it would be plausible? If so, you're welcome to make an answer. Unfortunately, I don't agree that it's common sense that that would be true, necessarily.

Comment: @Piomcron Would you mind addressing what I last said, or your original Question or preferably, both? Can I prove what, or demonstrate what would be plausible? What do you not agree would be true, necessarily? Otherwise, who doubted what you wanted to know? How could any Answer not still be "of course… That's what 'precog' is for"? If you want to make the shooter a precog, too, either that makes a different Question or they chase each other through an infinite series of time loops, or both. Why not go back and read your own Question again? Oops!

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin As I have defined it, the future is not fixed. If there a series of movements you could do to not get hit by a bullet, a precog could find it, but a bullet is incredibly fast. If someone pointed a gun at the centre of your chest and fired, by then it would be too late to stop them killing you. So really, instead of dodging a bullet you're trying to stop them pointing the gun at you long enough to fire. But the further away they are from you, the less movement they have to do to correct their aim every time you move.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I'm not convinced there would have to be any potential future where the precog could survive. If the gunman was able to keep the gun pointed in your direction for less than a second then they could shoot a bullet at the centre of your chest and it would hit you. What movements could you do from so far away that would impair their ability to do that? You can see what they'd do based on what you could do, but what good is knowing that they will continue to tilt the gun in your direction?

Comment: @Piomcron Jolly good and why does the target need to wait so long. Why can't your precog start cogging more previously?

Anyway it's your world. Why not just build it as you feel fit?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin 5 seconds is simply a hard limit. Put it this way: the precog knows in 5 seconds the gunman will attempt to shoot at him, almost no matter what. But if there's no cover, and the gunman's far away then what can the precog do with most of that time? Where the gunman actually shoots depends only on where the precog actually is in 4.99... or so seconds. So what options does the precog have?

Comment: @Piomcron You seem to be missing your own point, which is that the potential victim is and the gunman is not precognitive. Was that not your point?

"Where the gunman actually shoots depends only on where the precog actually is in 4.99... or so seconds" comes from a wholly different worldview; one which denies any meaning for precognition, wholly supplanting that with the ancient idea of Death on the road to Samarra 

Still it's your world. Why not just build it your way?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I have described and clarified a few times how the precognition works. It's not fixed or set in stone, involves seeing many probable futures, and although the precog can find favourable actions they can't lock the shooter's actions necessarily. They might be able to find the path where the shooter misses, but only if it's possible. The shooter reacts to every action taken, so where they shoot depends on what the precog does and where they are immediately before they shoot. Maybe I could handwave something once, but I want to know, based on the mechanics, in general.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin To put it another way, say you were playing chess with a Grandmaster. You're a precog who can see 20 moves into the future, and for every move you do you can see what they'd do. Assuming there are about 3 moves each time you could do that aren't obviously stupid, that's 59049 ways the board could be arranged in the future, and you can choose any of them. Is it a surefire way to win? No, since the gm played close to optimally in all of them. Maybe if you're a Master yourself. That's with symmetrical starting positions. But you have no gun. So remove your queen and rooks. Win?

Comment: @Piomcron To keep your way the same, if you want to Edit the Question, edit. If you want to stick with what you set out, stick. It's your Question, and which would you prefer?

Dragging ourselves back to when your “future is not fixed. If there a series of movements you could do to not get hit by a bullet, a precog could find it…” No buts.

Why is it not clear that “moving before the trigger is pulled, or feinting…” are so different, there could be no “something like that”?

The point is never to get into a position where the guy could point the gun at you.

Why consider anything else?

Comment: @Robbie Goodwin They can only see up to 5 seconds into the future. If they were out in an open field, and someone drove towards them to get in range of a shooter's gun, I'm not convinced there are a series of movements they could possibly do to avoid getting hit.

Comment: @Piomicron Of course you're not convinced, because obviously you're not considering what "pre-cog" might mean, with or without your five-second limitation.

Start not from the artificial point of the shooter aiming.

Start instead from five seconds before the two came across each other.

When was that, please?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Five seconds before that, the precog was walking alone on flat plains and became aware of a soon-to-be visible vehicle carrying the sniper.

Comment: Of course he did, and you can change the story as much as you want - what many people might call "cheating." Again, why not stick with what you set out, or edit the original? Neither is difficult.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I don't think I've changed anything at any point? I've elaborated some, asked for a general case, and here given a specific case.

Comment: Jolly good. then why not go back and add all your elaborations into the original, instead of slapping them on like sticking plasters? Remember a high-velocity rifle bullet is a bit faster and an ordinary pistol rather less than the 1,100 feet per second speed of sound… do your own arithmetic. It's true, most people shoot straighter than Lee Marvin in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_Ballou and still, Mr Average… but not many by much. As you said, what about moving before the trigger is pulled? Sneaking up behind and knocking Mr Shooter cold?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Because I want to know a more general answer, not just in this specific circumstance. This scenario is specific so you cannot sneak or hide behind cover, or shoot first, or get behind the shooter because you're too far away. I want to know, in general, if a precog could dodge a bullet.

Comment: After all this time… and here again, you're still adding restrictions someone didn't think of at first? In general, given anything like five seconds the Question isn't whether your precog could dodge your bullet, but why you don't see it as obvious.

Why not call in at your local gun club and ask for some pointers? You - oddly - said "a bullet is incredibly fast". It isn't, to anyone in the know - but even half a second, let alone five, will seem to you an incredibly long time when the chips are down. 

Why not go to Chat?

Why not be more specific next time?.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115976/discussion-between-piomicron-and-robbie-goodwin).

Answer (score 48):

## It's complicated:

First of all, kudos for limiting it to five seconds. More than that starts getting strange. Second, I strongly suspect you're going to start hitting a problem with precognition, which is that prediction alters reality which alters precognition. When your precognitive dodges the bullet, they're still visible and light travels REALLY fast. So naturally, the person alters their trajectory to compensate for where the bullet is going. This creates a nasty feedback where the character now has to dodge the NEW trajectory of the bullet, and all the reasonably probable trajectories of the bullet. Then there's dodging the second and third bullet, all of which may be in the next five seconds. While your character may avoid a lot of bullets at reasonably close range (especially with good reaction time against clumsy/slow opponents) I'd say **NO** to a short-ranged gunfight.

You **MAY** still be unbeatable in a gunfight, however. Rather than dodging bullets, you can anticipate where your opponents will be in the future and shoot them first. THEY have no ability to anticipate the bullets, so 9mm of prevention is worth 45 calibers of cure. Also, invest in a bulletproof shield, since they can't anticipate as well where THAT will be. Even a small one might be enough, and these would be useless in a normal gunfight but great for your character. You still get shot, but it won't be nearly as harmful (although anyone who's ever taken a bullet in a vest will tell you it's still a LOT of energy to dissipate).

Long range sniper fire, your character is golden (hard **YES**). Anything where the bullet already left the barrel by the time the character reacts, nothing the shooter can do will change the trajectory (unless it's a gyrojet smart projectile that tracks targets).

Ambush? The character will know it's coming and can take cover, jump behind people, or just drop suddenly. This greatly reduces the opportunity for a shooter to hit the character. This is especially true if the character isn't the intended target. So a hard **YES** to dodging stray bullets, if the character is in a position to maneuver. This also means the character would be the ultimate secret service agent—they could deliberately interpose themselves easily between an intended target and a shooter. Invest in good body armor.

Your ability to dodge spraying bullets will depend on the perception of the character. If they can see bullets (and I certainly can't, so just knowing bullets are fired doesn't guarantee you know where they will be) then they would be able to chart a course that misses many bullets. Human reaction isn't perfect, so they might misjudge, or slip, and not realize it until it's too late to change it. So **MAYBE** on random sprayed bullets.

Comment: keep in mind if cover is available, the chances of getting hit go down tremendously. The enemy has a lot less ability to compensate, and at close range the enemy has to make larger movements to compensate.

Comment: @John Very true. +1  Although the more clutter around, the more chance you'll find yourself in a position where you are unable to maneuver away. It's only five seconds. Kinda like a spider-sense.

Comment: If the bullet has already left the barrel when the character reacts, the character would have to be able to move fast enough to change position before the bullet reaches them. A bullet from a sniper rifle would probably travel at supersonic speed. It'd have to be at very long range.

Comment: @Pahlavan Almost all bullets travel at supersonic speeds, with a few exceptions, but the sniper rifle bullets are still admittedly really fast (but also massive and streamlined). There's still a notable lag between trigger and impact. Even one second is enough to dodge a bullet in this case. You could design an experiment where a target is connected to a trigger and veers in an unexpected direction at human speed on trigger squeeze. I'm betting it would make a small target unhittable.

Comment: This really hinges on if the precognition also includes meta-precognition, that is, can the precognitive vision see futures resultant of precognatively-made decisions? If so, the "feedback" loop never jumps into existence as the whole action-reaction-loop is all precogged and accounted for. In such a situation, any shooter will feel like they're never able to properly line up a shot, or if they're blind-firing, will feel like they aren't able to hit the target. The target will simply follow the dodging pattern ordained by precognition and not get hit.

Comment: @Dragongeek It does get a little tricky if there is only one possible outcome, but if that were the case, the power couldn't work because the character could only follow the "inevitable" final result. If the meta-cognition got too bad, then everything would be probability cones and virtual positions. Even with just five seconds, the possibilities would be mind-boggling. Telling now from future would be really strange. Since it is about the possible futures, I assume there's a limit to meta-precognition, but maybe there isn't. It's all up to the OP.

Comment: @DWKraus, you're right. I've thought on this a bit (and written my own answer) and concluded that if you take the 5-second precognition "all the way" the Precognative-User essentially reaches godlike levels of unstoppable when faced with anything short of carpet bombing--and even then, if they had a gun they might be able to shoot the bombs out of the air before they're killed. Similarly with your smart-bullet point--the precognative could just find the future where something causes it's guidance system to glitch, a bird to fly in its path, a reflection to confuse its sensor just right, etc.

Comment: "although anyone who's ever taken a bullet in a vest will tell you it's still a LOT of energy to dissipate" - I wonder... if the bullet came from a handheld gun, then the energy to dissipate would be the same as the energy the shooter took to his hand. For every action, there's an equal and opposite reaction after all. So, no stronger than a fist to the shield/armor, no?

Comment: @Vilx- Have you fired a lot of firearms? I find it a fairly visceral experience. The guns are designed with lots of systems to spread out and slow impact. The gun jerks violently and is very kinetic. Even the acceleration of the projectile happens over time inside the barrel. The movies showing people getting knocked over from shooting aren't just theatrics. The bullet, conversely, is designed to focus down the impact to the smallest possible point and over the shortest time possible. Your fist doesn't rip someone's skull apart. And that's the smallest of firearms.

Comment: At short range they’re safe too. Check the 15’ rule. At close range a knife man can kill faster than a policeman can draw, aim, and fire his gun. At very close range, you’ve got a surprisingly good chance of disarming someone pointing a gun at you before they commit to shooting. I mean, obviously don’t try it for fun, but it can be done. A precog would seem to have a great advantage here is knowing when their target is sufficiently distracted to give them an advantage by evaluating the outcomes.

Comment: I don't think feedback loop would be a problem. First of all the precog doesn't have to *act* 5 seconds prior to shot. He can delay his action 2-3 secs. Second - I don't have the stats for this, but reaction times for the shooters should also be in seconds' range. Afai remember the drivers' reaction times to things in road are measured to be on average around 1-2 secs. Same probably here.

Comment: @Vilx- The bullet has *momentum* equal and opposite to the recoiling gun, but far greater energy. Momentum is mass times velocity, so a bullet 1/100th the mass of a gun is shot with 100x the velocity of the recoil. But since energy is mass times velocity *squared*, the bullet has 100x the kinetic energy of the recoiling gun.

Comment: @NuclearWang - ... what? OK, I think this is a question for Physics SE.

Comment: @Gnudiff gunslinger's reaction times are well in sub-0.5s time. There's a difference in scenarios when someone is driving and then something unexpected happen and when someone already has finger on a trigger and waits for something to happen.

Comment: @Alexander ok then, the precog has to cut it close then.

Comment: The reason you feel a hit to armor more than recoil is stopping distance vs acceleration distance.  A bullet fired from a 30" barrel accelerates over that whole 30", but if it then hits what is normally less than 1" of body armor, since you are stopping it many times as fast as it was accelerated. This is comparable to the difference between falling onto a mattress and falling onto a tile floor.  They may both be absorbing about the same amount of energy, but the amount of time they do it in matters a lot.

Comment: This is actually a great argument for the shield though because you can design the shield to deform much more than body armor would because it is not actually touching your body.

Comment: I had the same thoughts about the feedback loop, where it would require the precog to only move after the shooter pulled the trigger. Also, bullets don't necessarily go faster than the speed of sound. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muzzle_velocity says they can go as slow as 120 m/s and the speed of sound is 343, per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_sound. And even an M16 round takes almost a second to travel to the max effective range of 800 m at 960 m/s. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M16_rifle

Comment: "9mm of prevention is worth 45 calibers of cure" This has got to be the best new proverb that I've heard in a long time

Comment: @Nosajimiki - Ohhhh! That makes sense! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 10):

**Single shot weapons.**

There is a game called Super Hot that presents a similar situation. Rather than precognizing where the bullets will land you can slow time to see where the bullets are. Note this also slows down the player so you can never move super fast. Might be worth a play to get a feel for what's possible!

The main thing you cannot dodge is a machinegun firing down a corridor. I know the corridor will be full of lead in the next 5 seconds. That's no use if I can't get out of the corridor before then.

Comment: The "precognition" you get in Super Hot is far less than 5 full seconds. With 5 seconds of precognition, you could dodge the bullet before the shooter even sees you or decides to shoot.

Comment: Bullets in SH are sloooow, slow enough that you can literally get out of the way while they are flying toward you. With most modern firearms, once the trigger has been pressed there is very little you can do.

Comment: @laancelot Imagine playing Superhot but the "bullets" are not the actual bullets. They are just visual indicators of your precognition for when the bullet will be fired. In reality the trigger is pulled almost exactly when the "bullet" hits you.

Comment: @Daron While it makes sense, it changes the dynamic that the choice of the action is owned by the shooter and not the precog. So that would work as you describe, but in a awfully dangerous and depressing way, as while the shooter isn't taking a shot the precog slowly (or rapidly) sees his survival window closing.

Comment: @laancelot I don't understand what you mean by "choice of the action is owned by the shooter and not the precog."

Comment: When the bullet is shot, the precog's special skill won't save him anymore if he's still in the way. His ability is quite formidable, but as he's not the one who decides when the bullet is shot, is the shooter is somewhat competent the precog will mostly see his options diminish while the shooter tries to get a bead on him until the precog have no options left but to be in the way of the (not yet shot) bullet. I didn't want to make this a deal breaker, though, just point out how awful it must be to see less and less safety and more and more death chances. It could be an awesome narrative tool.

Comment: @laancelot I'm afraid I still don't understand what you are trying to say. You say "it changes the dynamic". What was the dynamic before and what does it change to?

Comment: I'm referring to the Super Hot dynamic: you see the bullet coming (it leaves a trail so you can't miss seeing it). The precog is like the SH player, he knows where the bullet will pass, so he can avoid being there when it happens. Except that in SH the bullet have already been shot, it's comitted to this trajectory, whyle there's a feedback loop between the precog and the shooter which will only end when the shooter actually fire his weapon. Until then, he'll try to aim at the precog actively, which gradually reduce the precog's options until either the shooter miss or the shooter kills him.

Answer (score 10):

#### Yes, your character is basically unstoppable*

First, I'm going to assume that there is some sort of engine (extradimensional supercomputer, deity, alien, whater) which grants the powered individual this capability and interfaces directly with their brain (or soul depending on setting).

Secondly, I'm going to assume that whatever this Precognition Engine does isn't *true* precognition but rather *simulated* precognition. This means there's no actual time travel or future-observation going on, instead, the precognition engine is hooked up to some sort of panoptical system which is capable of viewing the users' entire (or even just local) reality at a particulate level (smaller or bigger adjust prediction accuracies). To "see" the future, the Engine performs simulations. This prevents nasty causality issues and the other weirdness that accompanies time travel.

Finally, I'm going to assume that the Engine is capable of precogging the power's user's brain, effectively granting meta-precognition. Otherwise, the user would only ever see one, rapidly shifiting future, since the Engine is capable of perfectly prediciting the future (in the short term).

Also, if your User has a gun, then they would be absolutely unstoppable.**

**A simulated gunfight, from the precognative side:**

The person who's connected to the Precognative Engine (the User) is of the opinion that they do not want to get shot. The Engine "knows" this (although it's not necessarily sentient).

Now, a gunman is approaching the user, and the Engine calculates that in five seconds, the gunman will have aimed, fired, and hit the User. Next, the Engine simulates what the User would choose to do when presented with this information, and the simulated User decides to, lets say, take a step to the left a second before the gun is fired. Simulating this course of action, the Engine discovers that the gunman is good enough to partially adjust their aim and the User get's winged on the arm instead. This data, is once again fed to the Engine's simulation of the User, which again "decides" to avoid this fate and chooses a different simulated action.

This simulate-query-resimulate loop continues onwards until the simulated User is presented with a satisfactory action, and this process works onwards continously.

The User, unaware of what's going on "behind the curtain" simply sees all the possible futures of the choices that simulated-User made and eventually settles on the same choice that simulated-User eventually made (free will is dead, but whatever). Then, they perform the exact set of actions that allow them to avoid getting shot.

**The same gunfight, but from the gunman's perspective:**

The gunman is a professional. They sight the User with their gun, line up a shot, and are about to press the trigger, when suddenly the User steps to the side a bit. The gunman readjusts their aim, but again, just before they're about to pull the trigger, the User is coincidentally not lined up properly anymore. Frustrated, they continue trying to get a bead on the User, but always just before they're about to fire the perfect shot, the User does something that makes them feel like they'd miss if they pulled the trigger. Eventually, the gunman can't take this anymore and losens their tolerances on what's an accepatable shot and starts shooting, even if they don't have a hit lined up. It dosen't help though, the User seemingly dances or limbos across the field of fire without getting hit once.

---

*There are scenarios where the User *can* get hit. Notably, they can get hit by area-affect weapons like bombs or grenades where they can't get out of the danger zone within five seconds (unless they can disable the bomb or grenade before it goes off, for example by shooting it or getting someone else to shoot it) or they can get hit by enough massed-fire, although it would take a serious amount of bullets to make it that there's no possible dodging window and the User would be stupid to put themselves in a situation like that. The most effective way to kill the User is to unknowingly poison them and then make sure they aren't in an enviroment where they can precognatively find the antidote or how to make an antidote in under 5 seconds.

**If the User has a gun, they basically become unstoppable. Then, they can do fancy things like:

- shoot opponents just right so they twitch and shoot their neighbors just right
- shoot bullets which ricochet just right and jams weapons
- shoot enemy vehicles just right so they get disabled instantly
- shoot bullets, grenades, etc out of the air with multiple ricochets
- etc

To highlight how ridiculously bullshit this power could be, imagine the user is in an empty field, with a gun, facing 12 professional soldiers. It's a standoff. Then, the User simply finds the future where shooting one of the soldiers *just right* makes them twitch their gun to the side and shoot 11 perfect, friendly-fire, headshots on their fellow squadmates before dying themselves. To see an example of what it could look like to watch a precognative fight, take a look at [this clip](https://youtu.be/qHFORem2Bj8?t=60) where Bart disables all her opponents, even when starting from extreme disadvantage (although the power Bart has is slightly different) or take a look at Contessa in Wildbow's *Worm* (although her power is also slightly different).

Comment: As you up the number of combatants you up the complexity enormously In a one on one fight or when up against a small group the 'seer' has an enormous advantage. If he's storming Omaha beach in June 1944? There would be to many complexities. Say he/she is  ducking and weaving up the beach and  'see's a future incoming stream of MG fire. Solution- drop into that shell hole just up ahead and stay down. All good. Right up to the moment the next barrage of incoming German artillery fire air - bursts over his general area and now he has to dodge a burst of shrapnel.

Comment: Although I suppose on second thoughts depending on how the 'gift' works it might be simple. If for example the character 'sees' all the outcomes where he dies as 'black nothingness' encompassing perimeter their  vision and all those futures where he is injured as a 'red zone' within the black zone then I suppose they could, by training or force of habit learn to ignore all of these and instinctively follow only the limited number of safe choices that reside along a path 'white' options at the center of their vision. Sought of like a runner following a moonlight path through a dark forest.

Comment: @Mon I'd argue Omaha beach would actually be easier for the precog to navigate because there's less "feedback"--the vast majority of bullets/shells/etc aren't being aimed specifically at them, so less simulations are required since precog-derived actions don't make gunners adjust their aim as often. As for artillery, well, 5 seconds is a long time. The precog can probably find a future where they shoot the shells out of the air, adjust reality so someone else does, or even prepare the ground in a specific way that will make the shell's fuze malfunction and not trigger the explosive

Comment: Possibly, there's a series of novels ( Alex Versus) whose central character more or less does this. However I also have to note that war cemeteries are full of soldiers killed by bullets that weren't consciously aimed at them. A case of huge numbers of bullets being in the air at any one time, thousands of individuals desperately trying to survive and random chance.

Comment: I think the reference to Worm's Contessa is notable, because she explicitly gets the required secondary power that you don't need to give your user: The ability to actually carry this out. I know there's a future in which me in a field against twelve guys could end in a single shot, or a word, or whatever... but I lack the skill to do it. You could show me exactly what to do and I'll still fail to carry it out myself. Take away that component of the power and it's much less broken (...but still tremendously broken)

Comment: @Phoshi Well, Contessa needs the "ability to execute" part of her powers because she's only given steps and not actual visions of the future. The precognative, on the other hand, would be able to see the future where they fumble the execution of a precognative choice which leads to more feedback loops. So, would they always end up acting out the "fumble future"? If so, that's one tragic hero--calable of seeing the future but not avoiding what's gonna happen. Imo, the "perfect execution" part is a fundamental aspect of what makes this precognative power work, so I'm including it.

Comment: Your "if the user has a gun, they basically become unstoppable" discussion seems to make a key assumption: namely, that there *is* some perfect shot that has all the right knock-on effects. It seems entirely plausible to me that even five full seconds is not enough to manipulate the state of the universe to a place where that's true -- what if *all* outcomes involve at least one of the twelve getting a good shot off before you finish your warmup?

Comment: @DanielWagner while my example is on the extreme end of improbability, the possibility space encompassing any 5 seconds of discrete time is vast and approaching infinite in count (imo). Also even if some of the soldiers do get shots off, the precognative can always dodge, shoot the bullets out of the air, block with their own gun, etc. Keep in mind that the ability also works on a social angle, and five seconds is long enough to say a short sentence. Maybe there's a key phrase that will make the soldiers stand down or hesitate for just a moment.

Comment: First, the precognition is too entangled with the user for the user to be able to predict their own actions. The precognition can't tell what the user will do in one second since they can't quite know what they will be showing them one second into the future. The user is given agency rather than predicting what they will do. Second, it's not that precise. If there are a general range of outcomes like 'moving your arm quickly to the left' rather than a slew of prerequisites then the precognition will be more aware of that.

Comment: the "unstoppable" scenario has the additional requirement that the precog is a perfect shooter. i may know perfectly well how i want to hit that billard ball, but that doesn't mean i will be able to.

Answer (score 5):

If your only enhanced skill is the 5 seconds of precognition, and you remain normal in every other way (no super fast reflexes etc.) then there are a few things you can do to lessen your chances of being shot. I'm assuming perfect precognition of all possible outcomes, along with an ability to perfectly adjust yourself in response to the precognition outcomes.

1. If there is cover really close by, you are golden. Just go there. Now they can't hit you.
2. No time to get to cover before the first shots are fired? You can feint. Move in such a way that will allow you to dodge (or if nothing else get shot in the least serious spot). An example would be shifting slightly so the bullet passes just past your body in the gap beneath your arm. Unfortunately, since the shooter can react to anything you do (I assume), any larger more obvious attempts to dodge (which would have to be begun sooner as well, giving them more chance to notice) may result in them altering their aim, resulting in a situation where you're committed to a movement and their adjustment results in you getting hit anyway. But since you can see all outcomes, you already know to avoid any motion where this will happen. Likely in 90% of cases, the most favorable outcome you find will be one where you only move slightly, at the latest possible moment, "tricking" the shooter into missing.
3. Captain America's shield or Wonder Woman's gauntlets. If you have something like this, you can dramatically reduce your risk of getting fatally shot. Simply move whatever it is in between you and the bullet. The smaller it is the better (Wonder Woman beats Cap, again I am assuming you are capable of making perfect movements in response to the precognition. If you can't be precise, then Cap beats Wonder Woman) since a smaller "shield" has less risk the enemy will realize you are blocking and change aim. HOWEVER unless said material is something super cool magic/sci fi tech that absorbs impact, this may still result in a lot of pain and or damage to you. All that energy from the bullet striking has to go somewhere, after all. Still better than the alternative of the bullet entering your body, though. The same principle goes for body armor. If you are wearing a bullet proof vest and your precognition tells you you can't dodge said bullet, just move so it hits you dead center of the vest and at least you won't die. Wearing body armor gives you more "options" for what you can do to result in a non-fatal or less serious injury outcome (at least in situations where your body armor is strong enough to stop whatever you are being shot with from that given range).

That said, depending on distances, cover, type of gun, etc., you are not always going to be able to escape. While you can use the tricks above to have an advantage and be far less likely to die than some other person in the same situation, there ARE going to be situations when you get shot anyway, because no matter WHAT you do it will happen regardless, in which case your precognition doesn't help you much.

Answer (score 4):

**No**

Guns shoot bullets *fast*. A quick search on handguns shows a it ranges from 2000k/h to more than double. Let's get that in perspective.

Imagine someone throwing a tennis ball as hard as they can at you from two to five meters away. It's difficult to dodge or feint. You might succeed sometimes and not at all with others.

Now imagine the same, only you are going in slow motion and the ball is not. Suddenly it's nearly impossible to dodge the ball.

With precognition you'll see a lot of outcomes where you'll be shot. Luckily there are probably outcomes where you won't get shot. With only five seconds to work with, you can only know definitely how to move to shake of their aim in those five seconds, making them miss or not shoot yet. The problem is that in the few possibilities you have to survive, some might lead to a dead end after the five seconds. Even with continuous precognition you might go and run into a hallway as it's your only way out, but find out quickly that when they turn the corner they'll shoot you.

In some situations you'll have some chance to evade fire, but I think even with the perfect precognition you describe you'll likely be shot if there's no cover available.

Unless talking is allowed. With seeing all the possibilities, you can also see what words will get you out of it. This can get them rich, or be a pressure point of their psychology or whatever. Many things might make them hesitant or not want to shoot you. I mean most people will want to capture him to check the stock exchange or bitcoin prices for example.

Comment: You say there are outcomes where you don't get shot, what do you mean by this? All the time you're moving the shooter is adjusting their aim. How can you be sure it's possible to outright evade the point where they're going to shoot? As the number of bullets in the air increases, it becomes increasingly unfeasible, as I alluded to in the OP. Talking is not particularly allowed, as the chances of you saying anything coherent are quite low, and your likely actions aren't modelled.

Answer (score 4):

## Does the shooter know you're a precog?

Because if he/she does, you're hosed. All I'd need to do is hold the gun on you and then start clogging up your precognition with false starts. Am I going to shoot or not? Now?  NOW? ***How about now?*** Of all those hundreds of possible futures that could happen in the next five seconds, every tenth of a second represents the possibility of an actual shot because I know you're a precog and I'm jumping random numbers through my head about when to pull the trigger.

If I'm good enough at it, you're vapor-locked because so many of the possible futures cause you're death, you don't know which one to react to — and all I need you to do is blink at the wrong moment once. *(Hah hah! picked the wrong tenth of a second suckah!)*

The movie *[Next](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Next_(2007_film))* makes the idea of precognition look almost godlike. But that's only true if the people you're reacting to don't know what you can do. When that's the case, they act very predictably.

When they know you. You're hosed.

*Bear in mind you can always create a boring godlike character. "The precog always knows the truth! The precog knows which moment will be the actual trigger pull and which are just fakes to try and clog the vision!" But your character needs limits to be relatable and believable. The twist to the movie* Next *was that in seeing any distance into time involving Jessica Biel (a middlin' actress... but well worth looking any distance into time...) the movie could create the ending surprise twist (also known as the TV show Dallas' "it was all a dream!" trope). But that ability was meant to bring about a specific plot condition. You must do the same. So, the reality is that your precog must have a weakness — and I think that weakness is that when people know they're facing a precog, they can jam the vision with a lot of false positives, which confuses the precog (what I'm calling vapor-lock).*

Comment: Or just use a shotgun.

Comment: @DKNguyen oh, that just takes the fun *right* out of it! In reality (and pulling this out of thin air), I suspect a precog as the OP describes might, maybe, dodge a single shot. But a shotgun, a machine gun, even a semi-auto is out of the question. I'd have to think about the timing - but I wouldn't be surprised if a second shot from a bolt-action rifle might be impossible to dodge. If nothing else, adrenaline eventually kicks in.

Comment: It just occurred to me we're just talking about anti-Jedi tactics.

Comment: Also, I just learned of HEIAP rounds which are basically little artillery shells. So just shoot at the ground around the precog. They'll eventually slow him down enough so no amount of precog will help.

Comment: You know, @DKNguyen, the more I think about it, the more precognition as a story element must basically adhere to the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle. You can either know what will happen or when it will happen - but you can't know both because the act of viewing the future changes it. That would also make a pretty good story. "I'm going to die!" "Do you know how?" "NO! But I know it'll be tomorrow at 2:17pm!" or "YES! I'll be stabbed!" "OK, when?" "I DON'T KNOW!" That would be a curse worthy of balancing the gift.

Comment: You can't do false starts unless you're rapidly changing your mind based on what they are doing. If you make a move to shoot but plan not to have shot by five seconds in the future then it will know.

Comment: @Piomicron That's assuming facts not in evidence. I can make a decision to talk, then change my mind, quite rapidly. Only the OP can tell us if the precog can tell the difference or not (but as I pointed out, if they can tell the difference, they're godlike and boring).

Comment: I mean, I am the OP. The precognition certainly knows the current situation with extreme accuracy, so if the plan is something you're going to stick to then it's no harder to model unless very slight differences in the user's actions change your actions drastically. You could certainly make an AI chip or targeting system to take full advantage but with your normal human reflexes and decisions I feel as though it would be incredibly difficult to confuse unless you had years of dedicated anti-precog training.

Comment: @Piomicron :-) Sorry about that. I didn't check and it's been a while since I saw this post. It's your story, so if you want to define your precog to be godlike, that's up to you. My point is that people, even trained people, can only multi-task so far before they become overwhelmed. That's a weakness that can be taken advantage of.

Answer (score 3):

That depends on your understanding of the nature of time, predestination, and the ability to alter the timeflow. That is, **it is your call (as the writer or game designer).** It comes down to a variant of the grandfather paradox.

- Under most conditions, five seconds are plenty to move the body so that no body part is where any other body part used to be.
- When a shooter fires an aimed shot, he or see will notice that the target has started to move and try to lead it.

So how will actions by the precog who has seen the future and wants to alter it affect other actors? Say the precog is sitting on a bench in a bar. The shot *is going to* go through his heart and then through the back rest. The precog stands up because of that warning. Does the future which *has been revealed* disappear, or does it have to happen? It was the most likely variant a couple of moments ago.

Those "strands" of yours, do they include the precog's own action? In 75% of the probabilities, I stand up, so let's not stand up and the shooter is confused?

If the shooter can react normally, I guess precognition isn't enough to escape.

Comment: A little nitpicky, but OP describes the precognition in terms of "processing power" and "possible futures" so to me it seems like there's no "true" precognition going on but rather something--for example a supercomputer--making simulations and using them to guess at futures. This sidesteps the paradox in my opinion because it should be well within the capabilites of the precognative engine to simulate what choices the actor will take, and adjust it's own simulations accordingly.

Comment: @Dragongeek, that's what I mean with the last couple of sentences. If it is *just* extrapolation, then the warning is a bit like the missile warning on a military transport aircraft -- yes, you're being illuminated, but what can you do about it? Outrun the missile? Dodge it?

Answer (score 3):

Here's an aid for the imagination.

First imagine that the gunman is instead holding a long thin rod, representing the trajectory of the bullet. As he waves it around, can you dodge above or below it and avoid being touched by the rod? If you are standing close enough and are suitably agile and acrobatic, possibly. For a short time, anyway. You may have seen people dodging a long sword like this, for example. The further away you are, the faster the rod moves and the easier it is to change its direction of swing, and so the harder it is to dodge.

Now imagine that the rod has a flag attached, that traces out the path of the rod for the last 5 seconds. The trailing edge of the flag represents where the gun was pointing 5 seconds ago. Can you dodge the trailing edge?

From the point of view of the precognitive, it is as if they can see the flag being waved 5 seconds into the future, so 'now' appears 5 seconds ago, and they only have to dodge the trailing edge of the flag. With 5 seconds warning, you have much more time to get out of the way of it. You can either duck under or jump over a moving line quite easily given 5 seconds notice. You should therefore be able to avoid it at a greater range.

But then, you can also see that one sweep at waist height to get you to duck low followed by a low sweep back to catch you before you can jump again may be much harder to avoid. It's a way to think about tactics.

Comment: This is not taking into account guy with the flag reacting to your modified movements.

Comment: The rod is a nice touch. When you put it that way, very good martial artists have a good chance of dodging a rod like that realtime in close ranges. And the longer the range, the more actual time you have where the bullet's path is locked and you have more potential motion to dodge with. But you can't treat it as if you know the path of the rod 5 seconds in advance because where the rod will end up depends directly on what you do before that point.

Answer (score 2):

> is it possible for them to not get hit by bullet**s** by moving away?

DWKraus's answer gives a very detailed explanation of what it would take to dodge or evade a bullet. That's all fine and good, but you asked about bullets *plural*, and that one extra 's' changes the situation significantly.

If you knew where a bullet was coming, how would you evade it?  You'd drop to the ground, dive out of the way, leap to the side, etc. All of these actions give your body a lot of momentum (most likely in a direction that you wouldn't normally be moving) and place you in a posture/position quite different than where you started. When your attacker adjusts and takes their second shot, they're going to see you moving and aim based on your new trajectory.  You don't just have to predict the bullet and react, you have to first cancel your current momentum and throw your body in a completely different direction.  If you're in the process of diving to the ground, all the precognition in the world can't stop your midair free-fall, stand you back on your feet, and prime your muscles for another evasive maneuver. The amount of time it takes your body to complete the first dodge and recover effectively eats away at your precognition buffer (it's future that you can "see" but can't do anything to change).  You'll likely have half the reaction time for the second shot. By the time they fire their third shot, the benefits of precognition are more or less nullified.

This calculus obviously changes if the attacker is using a weapon that can't immediately be fired again (like a black powder rifle, or they used the last round in the magazine). The time required to reload, re-arm, and re-aim the weapon all work in your favor.  If you can pick yourself up and start moving again before they can fire the next shot, then you should be okay. Against most modern weapons, though, you'll want to make sure that your initial evasive maneuver takes you behind cover or into an otherwise protected position.  You can't afford to give them a second chance.

Comment: I agree, but if you read my answer, I do mention that the second and third bullet are major reasons why close gunfights are a no. Also a big reason why sprayed gunfire is, at best, a maybe. Still, +1

Answer (score 1):

**You can dodge the bullets.  You can do more than that.**

In the movie Next, Nick Cage's character can see 3 minutes into the future.  This clip is towards the end of the movie.  He sees all possible futures and evades the ones where he gets shot.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RC5ZiK6o7uQ

I feel like you might not know about this movie, Piomicron and so I hesitate to share the clip because it is a very cool movie and this is one of the coolest scenes.  If you dig stuff like this, stop the video right after the bullet scene because otherwise it will spoil the end.  Rent it!  Next is a fine film; one of Cage's best and I have never seen a Julianne Moore movie I did not enjoy.  Also: Jessica Biel!

Comment: The problem is that if the number of bullets is sufficiently high, it might happen, that among all the different scenarios 5 seconds into the future, there is not a single one where the precog will *not* be hit. So the only choice might be, where do you want to get hit.

Comment: Movies are not always known for their realism, so unless I know how it was modelled then I can't really use it as justification. Movies take frequent breaks from reality and logical conclusions according to their own established rules for the sake of coolness. The movie looks interesting though, so I might give it a watch.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the battle situation.  If you have good cover available and aren't too badly outnumbered you can avoid their fire.  You know when and where it will be safe to expose yourself for a moment to shoot at them and you know exactly where to place that shot.

However, this will not protect you if there's no cover within 5 seconds, or if you are outnumbered to the point there is no safe spot to pop up for a shot.  You jump behind the block of concrete, there are guns aimed all around the concrete, there's nothing you can do while they walk up and toss a grenade.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, knowing that the room you're in is going to be riddled with bullets in 5 seconds might not be enough for you to run to safety.

In addition, keep in mind that anyone you're fighting can also see the future, to a lesser degree - because you can see the future, and they can see you. If you suddenly jump to the right, they won't bother shooting to the right and will shoot left instead. While your head is in the rapidly changing timelines five seconds from now, they are in the present and have much less to think about. (Read the Mistborn trilogy to see this done in proper epic fashion).

Comment: I have read most of the Cosmere, and that scene is indeed really cool. But I think that strictly speaking, you should already be seeing loads of atium shadows at once.

Answer (score 1):

## Bullets are surprisingly "slow".

Next time you're out in the desert shooting your handgun at rocks a few dozen feet away, **put in some tracer rounds**.

(They "light up" like in a video game and you can see them going along.)

Humans have incredibly fast acuity time.  (Witness video games like Splatoon, where one frame, about 1/50th of a second, is a completely normal operating time for players.)

Amazingly the first time you do this, you'll actually "see" the bullet going from your gun to the rocks over there.  (You'd probably guess before trying this, that it's "too fast to see", that you wouldn't actually "see it travel", but you do.)

The simple answer to your question is that for Really Long Sniper Shots (Like Riggs In Lethal Weapon) **it takes bullets a full second or two to get there**.

(Definitely not as long as "five seconds" - but a couple seconds.)

## The bottom line is, "sniper shots" are 1-2 seconds.

Really, based on that info, you would formulate what happens in your story. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how fast your brain can process all those future possibilities.
If your brain can process all those possibilities, then choose the most probable outcome, and finally decide a response to the enemy's action in less than a second, then your ability would really be useful.
But since, like other answers, future would change because of our action, the actually useful precognition would be shorter than 5 seconds. This is because our action, and how the enemy responds to our action, would result in a new set of future outcome.
In this form, the ability would look similar to the ZERO system in Gundam Wing and the the Geass of the Knight of One in Code Geass. The ones using this power must have a strong will to stare into future, not fooled by the precognition, yet not consumed by paranoia.
If you know you are going into a gunfight, then you could put a bullet through the other guy before his hand even start moving to his gun because you know when he is going to draw. He can't unleash his infinite-bullet minigun if he is dead before he could fire it. Even if he is behind cover, you know when he is going to pop out and open fire an instant before he shoot.
Even if you don't know you are going into a fight (like a sniping), you can dodge or get away, because the bullet takes time to gravel, the assassin needs time to get into position, etc.
Of course, all of these depends on you know how to respond to these situation, have the tools to protect yourself, and are in a condition to act on self-preserving. If you are tied to a pole facing a fire squad, then the best you can do is yell something incomparably cool So you can die with dignity and awesomeness and won popularity among fans. Who knows, if you got enough popularity, the studio would revive you in the next season.

Comment: Processing power is one of the aspects of the power as I mentioned in the OP.